# How can I fix/ workaround this KeyError when I try to extract from a json via my python API request?

Tags: python, django, api, keyerror

I have been trying to seed a django DB with some covid data from an api and get a KeyError for a particular data type - in the source it is a floating_timstamp ("lab_report_date" : "2014-10-13T00:00:00.000"). (edit: not sure if the type is relevant, but trying to be comprehensive here).

I tried doing a more simple API request in python but get the same keyError. Below is my code and the error message.

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/naz8-j4nc.json")
print(response.json())
```

The output looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "cases_age_0_17": "1",
        "cases_age_18_29": "1",
        "cases_age_30_39": "0",
        "cases_age_40_49": "1",
        "cases_age_50_59": "0",
        "cases_age_60_69": "0",
        "cases_age_70_79": "1",
        "cases_age_80_": "0",
        "cases_age_unknown": "0",
        "cases_asian_non_latinx": "1",
        "cases_black_non_latinx": "0",
        "cases_female": "1",
        "cases_latinx": "1",
        "cases_male": "3",
        "cases_other_non_latinx": "0",
        "cases_total": "4",
        "cases_unknown_gender": "0",
        "cases_unknown_race_eth": "1",
        "cases_white_non_latinx": "1",
        "deaths_0_17_yrs": "0",
        "deaths_18_29_yrs": "0",
        "deaths_30_39_yrs": "0",
        "deaths_40_49_yrs": "0",
show more (open the raw output data in a text editor) ...

        "hospitalizations_unknown_gender": "3",
        "hospitalizations_unknown_race_ethnicity": "16",
        "hospitalizations_white_non_latinx": "135"
    }
]
```

So far so good, but if I try to extract the problem key, i get the KeyError:

```
report_date = []
for i in response.json():
    ls = i['lab_report_date']
report_date.append(ls)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/h3/5wlbmz0s3jb978hyhtvf9f4h0000gn/T/ipykernel_2163/2095152945.py in <module>
      1 report_date = []
      2 for i in response.json():
----> 3     ls = i['lab_report_date']
      4 report_date.append(ls)

KeyError: 'lab_report_date'
```

This issue occurs with or without using a for loop. I've gotten myself real turned around, so apologies if there are any errors or omissions in my code.

Comment: Can you just skip the entry if `lab_report_date` is not present?

Comment: It means that the `key`  `lab_report_date` is not present in the `response.json()` `dict` element. Or in some `dict` element, it's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there's an item in the array response.json() that does not contain a key `lab_report_date`. That happens when the backend data is not so clean.

So what you need to do is to use try-except code block to handle this exception. The following code runs well now.

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/naz8-j4nc.json")
print("The total length of response is %s" % len(response.json()))

report_date = []
for i in response.json():
    try:
        ls = i['lab_report_date']
        report_date.append(ls)
    except:
        print("There is an item in the response containing no key lab_report_date:")
        print(i)

print("The length of report_date is %s" % len(report_date))
```

The output of the above code is as follows.

```
The total length of response is 592
There is an item in the response containing no key lab_report_date:
{'cases_total': '504', 'deaths_total': '1', 'hospitalizations_total': '654', 'cases_age_0_17': '28', 'cases_age_18_29': '116', 'cases_age_30_39': '105', 'cases_age_40_49': '83', 'cases_age_50_59': '72', 'cases_age_60_69': '61', 'cases_age_70_79': '25', 'cases_age_80_': '14', 'cases_age_unknown': '0', 'cases_female': '264', 'cases_male': '233', 'cases_unknown_gender': '7', 'cases_latinx': '122', 'cases_asian_non_latinx': '15', 'cases_black_non_latinx': '116', 'cases_white_non_latinx': '122', 'cases_other_non_latinx': '30', 'cases_unknown_race_eth': '99', 'deaths_0_17_yrs': '0', 'deaths_18_29_yrs': '0', 'deaths_30_39_yrs': '0', 'deaths_40_49_yrs': '1', 'deaths_50_59_yrs': '0', 'deaths_60_69_yrs': '0', 'deaths_70_79_yrs': '0', 'deaths_80_yrs': '0', 'deaths_unknown_age': '0', 'deaths_female': '0', 'deaths_male': '1', 'deaths_unknown_gender': '0', 'deaths_latinx': '0', 'deaths_asian_non_latinx': '0', 'deaths_black_non_latinx': '0', 'deaths_white_non_latinx': '1', 'deaths_other_non_latinx': '0', 'deaths_unknown_race_eth': '0', 'hospitalizations_age_0_17': '30', 'hospitalizations_age_18_29': '78', 'hospitalizations_age_30_39': '74', 'hospitalizations_age_40_49': '96', 'hospitalizations_age_50_59': '105', 'hospitalizations_age_60_69': '111', 'hospitalizations_age_70_79': '89', 'hospitalizations_age_80_': '71', 'hospitalizations_age_unknown': '0', 'hospitalizations_female': '310', 'hospitalizations_male': '341', 'hospitalizations_unknown_gender': '3', 'hospitalizations_latinx': '216', 'hospitalizations_asian_non_latinx': '48', 'hospitalizations_black_non_latinx': '208', 'hospitalizations_white_non_latinx': '135', 'hospitalizations_other_race_non_latinx': '31', 'hospitalizations_unknown_race_ethnicity': '16'}
The length of report_date is 591
```

Comment: Ah, should have figured that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dict get method to read the data from json response like below :-

```
report_date = []
for i in response.json():
    if type(i) == dict:  # Just check the type to avoid the runtime error.
        ls = i.get('lab_report_date', None)
        if ls:
            report_date.append(ls)
```

Comment: Hmm. will have to try this out.

Answer (score 1):

**hi i have a similar issue which is sometimes the response comes empty
from the api request which cause to me a stop in the Code Execution :**

i found an easy solution for it now :

let's say you have a :

> requestfromapi = requests.get("https://api-server")

```
if requestfromapi.json()['data']['something'] != KeyError:

   print(requestfromapi.json()['data']['something'])
```

**// this will make sure that your code will not stop from executing .**

Comment: This is great.  I ended up using a try except method that works similarly.